# Sync mailchimp campaign click and open with some other database

Tags: mailchimp

I am working on mailchimp integration.
I need to pull campaign stats (opens and clicks) and put it in my local database.

Using mailchimp api i am getting the list of all the users with their action taken.

But my issue is how to keep data sync at all time.
Is there any way to skip that data from mailchimp api that i had synced already.

Comment: What method are you using to get campaign stats?   campaignStats or ?

Comment: I am using campaignEmailStatsAIMAll  as i need to sync open and sync history of all members along with the time when they took that action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the entire data set can change between calls and there is no 'since' parameter... The only way to get an updated picture is to query all records and update....

Keeping stat "data synced at all times" really would just depend on your solution (have it query for updates when you/your users access that section...)

You could expidite the update process by keeping track of previous calls/updates with the timestamp (keep track of the timestamp and only update/add records that are newer than the last sync...  )

As I said, there is currently no "since" command for the campaignEmailStatsAIMAll method (and no direct equivelent in the export API...)

A 'since' parameter would actually be a good feature...  So if coding your own solution to track updates via the timestamp is undesirable, you may want to ask the question in the google group or post a feature request in the google code project:

http://code.google.com/p/mailchimp-api/

---

EDIT: I just opened the feature request as it may solve a similar issue for an upcomming project:
http://code.google.com/p/mailchimp-api/issues/detail?id=60

Comment: yeah that's what i am doing now..  and it will really helpful if any such feature will be provided by mailchimp in future. thanks for your suggestion